# Istio Destination Rule has an order?

Tags: istio

```
- route:
    - destination:
        host: A
        subset: v1
        port:
          number: 80
  match:
    - uri:
        exact: /articles
    - uri:
        regex: \/articles
- route:
    - destination:
        host: B
        subset: v1
        port:
          number: 80
  match:
    - uri:
        exact: /articles
    - uri:
        regex: \/articles
```

Say I have something like this, which rules will be applied for /articles as all the match will be hit?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a destination rule but a VirtualService. Matching occurs in order.

Comment: So the first match will be routed? i.e. `exact: /articles` in host A.

Comment: Yes, so you need to put the most generic match as the last and the most specific the first.

Comment: is there a way to use regex on URI in the Istio destination rule?